# Arduino Uno does not detect the GPS module

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, gps, tinygps

I am trying to start the GLONASS NEO-7M-C module using TinyGPS++ liblary, but in the serial monitor I receive a message all the time that the module is not detected.

My connection:

- PPS - None
- RX - 4
- TX - 3
- GND - GND
- VCC - 5V

[image]

Comment: is RX wired to TX?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I connected the RX to pin 4 and TX to pin 3

Comment: Don't post screen shots of your code, post it within your question.

Comment: but 4 is RX of SoftwareSerial in your code or not? so receive to receive, transmit to transmit?

Comment: Yes you are right. Everything works well already. Thank you for your help!